# Homotopy push-out squares and exact triangles are colimits

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, limits-colimits, triangulated-categories

I read somewhere that homotopy push-out squares and exact triangles in a triangulated category can both be interpreted as special cases of higher categorical colimits. Why is this true?

Please note that I am indeed a beginner in category theory, so a rough intuition of the analogy would be more than enough for me. I am fully aware this would sacrifice precise formalism, but I am looking for the general idea here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, boy, this is a very long story to tell!

I will indeed sacrifice formalism to convey intuition: roughly speaking, a triangulated category arises as a certain kind of homotopy category, i.e. a category $C$ where you have some notion of weak equivalence, i.e. a class of maps you want to treat as if they were invertible.

Now, you can think of homotopy categories as arising as "1-dimensional shadows" of higher categorical concepts: intuitively, a 1-category is objects+morphisms; a higher category has higher-dimensional "cells" "filling" "commutative" "diagrams" (each of these words is better left undefined).

$$
\begin{array}{c}
\text{higher categories} \ni \mathcal K\\ 
\downarrow \\
\text{1-categories} \ni K
\end{array}
$$ where the correspondence "flattens" all the higher-dimensional information, forgetting all the stuff that lies beyond dimension 1.

If you're familiar with simplicial complexes, the intuition behind truncating a simplicial complex carries over here, again with some magic spell muttered here and there.

Now, a fundamental tenet of Platonism, as well as of higher category theory is that very little can be said about an object, judging the shadow it casts: so, it turns out that construction in triangulated categories, like distinguished triangles and homotopy colimits, lack the universal properties they had "upstairs" when regarded as shadows.

In short: the object $\mathcal K$ has a true and very clear universal property, but it is extremely difficult to define and handle the place where it belongs to; otoh, its shadow $K$ is extremely unnatural to define (it's not a real colimit, just a shadow thereof), but the place where it lives is way more ergonomic.

Comment: I feel like I am lacking sufficient background, so I beg you pardon if it was already implicit in your answer: what role do homotopy pushout squares play here “[...] like distinguished triangles and homotopy colimits, lack the universal properties they had "upstairs" when regarded as shadows.”?

Comment: Pushouts are a certain kind of colimit, similarly homotopy pushouts are certain kind of homotopy colimit. The problem with the universal properties in the homotopy world is that the universal morphisms need not be unique anymore but only unique up to homotopy, with the homotopy itself being unique up to homotopy etc. To express this is what $\infty$-categories are for. In some cases you only care about the existence of the universal arrow and the uniqueness becomes a secondary problem. In this case you might get away with homotopy categories (like triangulated categories)

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: There's not very much to add! I tried to summarise the situation in appendix A of my PhD thesis http://tetrapharmakon.github.io/stuff/main.pdf I don't know if it can be helpful, because it presupposes a bit of terminology, but I believe I made the overall idea and narrative elementary enough... hope it helps!